# A question on permutation.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in {\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}}$ be normal and ${\lambda _1},{\lambda _2},.....,{\lambda _n}$ be its eigenvalues.

Why there is a permutation $σ$ of the integers $1, . . . , n$ such that $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{{\left| {{a_{ii}} - {\lambda _{\sigma (i)}}} \right|}^2}}  \le \sum\limits_{i \ne j} {{{\left| {{a_{ij}}} \right|}^2}} $.